# Threads Streaming video

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a Server in Java and a Client in Android. In Android I have an AsyncTask for the receive of the video  **continuous** by the server and a Thread that read the video with the MediaPlayer.

I launch the MediaPlayer after 5s but **only** the receipt packets are read at the moment when the MediaPlayer is launched.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    handler = new Handler();



    vidSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfView);


    ConcurrentLinkedDeque<OutputStream[]> list = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>();


    Connexion connexion = new Connexion(list);
    connexion.execute();

    new Thread(new Task2(list)).start();
}


private class Connexion extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ConcurrentLinkedDeque<OutputStream[]> list;

    public Connexion(ConcurrentLinkedDeque<OutputStream[]> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ConcurrentLinkedDeque<OutputStream[]> list = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>();

        DownloadVideo dv = new DownloadVideo(list);
        dv.connexion();

        return null;
    }
}

public void launchVideo() {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        vidHolder = vidSurface.getHolder();
        vidHolder.addCallback(this);
}

class Task2 implements Runnable {
@Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("1", "Thread2");
                launchVideo();
            }
        });
    }
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should not use an AsyncTask for something that runs continuously, it is intended rather for tasks that get completed.  Also, you should probably trigger you video start by the receipt of some cushion's worth of data, not by time.  You seem to be missing the code for DownloadVideo.java

Comment: If i can't use AsyncTask What can I use?

Comment: https://github.com/rfqu/AsyncConnector is a replace for AsyncTask, able to run continuously.

Answer (score 0):

Download Video :

```
public void connexion() {
        try {
            client = new Socket(IP_SERVER, 9003); // Creating the server socket.

            if (client != null) {
                // Receive video
                InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
                OutputStream out[] = new OutputStream[1];
                // Store on device
                out[0] = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Movies/chrono2.mp4");
                byte buf[] = new byte[1024];

                int n;
                while ((n = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
                    out[0].write(buf, 0, n);
                    //Adding last in the queue
                    list.addLast(out);
                    Log.d("byte" , "" + out);

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: This is not an answer and must not be posted as such.  Perhaps it should be an edit to your question, but it still seems incomplete.